# System was using bandwidth after windows 10 1909 upgrade

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I have upgraded to windows 10 1909 through windows upgrade assistant and it download an ESD file size 3.37GB. The upgrade was complete and I removed the ESD file somewhere else from where it was originally downloaded. But suddenly when I connected to the wifi it started using data took upto 1.1GB. I have  updated the windows right after upgrading from windows update.

But my question is why was system using data?

Is it because I removed the ESD file and it was downloading the missing files?

Or the system has to use data after the upgrade?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/esd-file-2621103 may be helpful

Comment: Typically, the best way to clean up your hard drive(s) after a Windows update is to use Disk Cleanup. You can find this in the Start Menu and also, if you right click on a drive like C: and choose "Properties" there should be a button there on the lower right-hand corner [Disk Cleanup].